# Handling Windows 11 UX with the taskbar on the bottom?

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

On Win10, I have the taskbar on the left (vertical). With Win11's taskbar on the bottom, there are these issues:

- with my monitor above my laptop, it's hard to open the taskbar on the monitor because the cursor often enters the laptop
- with Picture in Picture on the bottom left, it covers the time and taskbar icons

Is there a way to fix these issues?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about - how is Windows 10 related? How is taskbar on the left related?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the Windows 11 Start menu to work more like that of
Windows 10 - you need to replace it with a third-party Start menu.

Here are some candidates :

- [Open Shell](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/) (free)
- [StartAllBack](https://www.startallback.com/) (free)
- [Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/) (€6.99)

There exist other possibilities, but if you look further, do not try
the product ExplorerPatcher, as it can cause stability problems
to Windows.